# Jetpack Compose displays wrong colours

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Has anyone else came across this? As seen in [photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pMON.png) my surface background is white, yet displayed on the preview and in app is a purple colour. Same applies to the text views, they should be a black and grey colour but displayed as purple.

My code below

```
@Composable
fun EditableSettingItem(setting: EditableSetting) {
Surface(color = Color(R.color.background),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(86.dp)) {

    Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        Text(text = setting.settingName,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 19.dp, top = 14.dp)
                .wrapContentSize(),
            style = TextStyle(fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_regular)),
                fontSize = 13.sp,
                color = Color(R.color.sub_text)))

        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
            Text(text = setting.action,
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(),
                style = TextStyle(fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.quicksand_regular)),
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                    color = Color(R.color.main_text)))

            Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_chevron_right),
                contentDescription = null,
                alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd)

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the [mcve]. If you can do that, I can provide a better answer for your question, and your question will benefit more people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using `Color(R.color.background)`. `Color()` takes the hex value of a color, not an ID of a color resource.

Instead, [try `colorResource(R.color.background)`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/ColorResources.android.kt;l=32?q=colorResource&ss=androidx). That takes a color resource ID and returns the underlying color, wrapped in a `Color` object.